# Recuperar parâmetros com $_GET e $_POST no mesmo arquivo php, é correto?

Tags: php, ajax, http-request

Estudei php no começo da minha carreira acadêmica. Ao revisar meus códigos, em um deles, reparei que havia essa requisição:

app.js:

```
fetch(URL + ?controller=UserController&action=insert,
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                })
```

fetch.php:

```
 $controllerName = $_GET['controller'];
 $actionName = $_GET['action'];
 $nome = $_POST['nome']
```

Em fetch.php, para recuperar os dados do formulário passados no corpo da requisição, utilizo `$_POST` e para recuperar o parâmetro passado na `url`, utilizo `$_GET`. É boa prática utilizar os dois no mesmo arquivo php sendo que estou fazendo um requisição via método "`POST`" ou isso é opcional por ser característica da linguagem?

Comment: Sim, porque você está passando uma informação via *query string* da URL. Por mais que o PHP chame de `$_GET`, não há uma relação direta com o método `GET` do HTTP. Na verdade, o nome (e a existência) dessas variáveis foram uma infelicidade no desenvolvimento da linguagem por induzir o desenvolvedor a essa relação que não existe.

Comment: Francis, De uma maneira simplória, os verbos `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `PATCH` e outros representam uma semântica sugerida para que os sistemas fiquem mais claros. É como cada um deles definissem uma ação clara que está sendo requisitada ao sistema e este deve estar preparado para isso. Veja mais sobre RESTful, é uma boa abordagem. Acredito que os padrões sugeridos e adotados por muitos tem sempre seu valor, assim, sugiro ler sobre RESTful para ter uma organização das informações. Não sou especialista em PHP, mas acredito que neste exemplo ele está recebendo um `POST` e está tratando a `

Comment: Entendi. Então os métodos não tem relação direta. Obrigado por me ajudar.